# How do I make fraction within matrix display increase font and spacing?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I have an equation in LaTeX that currently looks like below, but how can I make the fraction within the matrix the same as the rest of the equation? Also, the spacing between the numerator and denominator is so close.

Things I've tried:

- Setting normal font size (`\normalsize`) inside a `\begingroup` or a `\begin{equation}`
- `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`: this just increased the space between the two matrix rows

Is this an issue of width?

My Packages:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
```

My EQ code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \noindent
    \centering
    \label{eq:coancestry_allfreq}
        \Pr(G_i)
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{[2\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i] \times [3\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i]}{(1+\theta)(1+2\theta)}  & G_i = aa \\
        \frac{2[\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i] \times [\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_j]}{(1+\theta)(1+2\theta)}  & G_i = ab 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `\normalsize` and `\noindent` are text-mode commands. They do nothing useful in math mode. Omit them.
- TeX's four math styles are `\displaystyle` (the default in, you guessed it, display-math mode), `\textstyle` (the default in inline-math mode), `\scriptstyle` (for first-level super- and subscripts; 30% smaller than `\textstyle`), and `\scriptscriptstyle` (for second-level super- and subscripts; ca. 30% smaller than `\scriptstyle`, or 50% smaller than `\textstyle`).
- Inside a `bmatrix` environment, the default math style is `\textstyle`. If the prevailing math style is `\textstyle`, the numerator and denominator of a `\frac`tion are typeset in `\scriptstyle`.
- I guess that what you're looking to accomplish is to typeset the numerators and denominators not in `\scriptstyle` but in `\texststyle`, (ca 1/0.7-1=42% larger than `\scriptstyle`). This may be accomplished by using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`. `\dfrac` is a macro provided by the `amsmath` package. The result of making this switch is shown in equation (1) below.
- You may also want to think about whether employing a `bmatrix` environment is indeed optimal, from a typsetting perspective. For instance, you may want to consider using a `dcases` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package) instead; see equation (2) below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath}   % amsmath is loaded automatically by mathtools
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:coancestry_allfreq}
\Pr(G_i) =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{[2\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i] \times [3\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i]}{(1+\theta)(1+2\theta)}  & G_i = aa \\[2ex]
    \dfrac{2[\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i] \times [\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_j]}{(1+\theta)(1+2\theta)}  & G_i = ab 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\begin{equation} \label{eq:coancestry_allfreq_2}
\Pr(G_i) =
    \begin{dcases}
    \frac{[2\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i] \times [3\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i]}{(1+\theta)(1+2\theta)}  & \text{if $G_i = aa$} \\
    \frac{2[\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i] \times [\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_j]}{(1+\theta)(1+2\theta)}  & \text{if $G_i = ab$}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this fixed everything and yes I agree, I don't think the square brackets really show it in the best way. I like the way you've done it in your second one! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\dfrac` command for display style fractions. I propose also to increase the spacing between rows of the matrix with the option `math` of the `cellspace` package. Note that you don't have to load the amsmath package when you load mathtools: the latter does it for you.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage[math]{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \noindent
        \centering
        \label{eq:coancestry_allfreq}
            \Pr(G_i)
        =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \dfrac{[2\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i] \times [3\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i]}{(1+\theta)(1+2\theta)} & G_i = aa \\
            \dfrac{2[\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_i] \times [\theta+(1-\theta)\hat{p}^2_j]}{(1+\theta)(1+2\theta)} & G_i = ab
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]